# How to find a point between two positive (or negative) charges where a third charge would remain stationary?

Tags: forces, electric-fields, charge

If for example there are two charges 9 and 5 coulombs on a plane a meter apart. How can a point be found where the net force on a test charge would be zero. I understand that all the net forces need to be added. But the problem is since the charges have the same sign just adding them and saying that it is equal to zero doesn't work, since I end up with zero in the denominator. So, how should this problem be approached properly?

Comment: Why do you think it's possible at all? That is, that you could find a point of stable equilibrium?

Comment: Well, one needs to add the forces as vectors, not simple scalar addition. This means that we must effectively subtract the fields as they act in opposite directions.

Comment: This is the marble on a sphere problem.  The stationary point is unstable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets put those two charges along the x axis 
Now we shall place a test charge and sum the overall force forcing him to move. Lets neglect gravity . 
F₁=-F₂
F=⃗E⃗*Q
⃗E⃗⃗= k qᵢ/xi²
when the first charge is located at the origin 
and the second on the (x₀-x) coordinate which x₀=1 meter
sum those two forces up to get a total of zero force to get the exact coordinate x to put a test chatge between them